# Trace mobile tower signals in android

Tags: android

Can anyone suggest way to trace the mobile tower signals in android. Tracing means (name,signal strength)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please go through this site for further information on Signal strength in Android.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SignalStrength.html

Comment: Thanks, But is it possible to get the name of mobile tower.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ConnectivityManager Class for such requirement.

Please visit this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html).

Comment: Thanks, But is it possible to get the name of mobile tower.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class GetGsmSignalStrength extends Activity
{
/* This variables need to be global, so we can used them onResume and onPause method to
  stop the listener */
TelephonyManager        Tel;
MyPhoneStateListener    MyListener;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    /* Update the listener, and start it */
    MyListener   = new MyPhoneStateListener();
    Tel       = ( TelephonyManager )getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
  Tel.listen(MyListener ,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);
}

/* Called when the application is minimized */
@Override
protected void onPause()
{
  super.onPause();
  Tel.listen(MyListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
  }

/* Called when the application resumes */
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
   super.onResume();
   Tel.listen(MyListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);
  }

/* —————————– */
/* Start the PhoneState listener */
/* —————————– */
 private class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener
 {
  /* Get the Signal strength from the provider, each tiome there is an update */
   @Override
   public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength)
   {
      super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Go to Firstdroid!!! GSM Cinr = "
         + String.valueOf(signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength()),         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

This might be useful to you